# Finding out the unique value from two different tables with different column names

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am trying to find unique values by comparing the two tables resultsets. I have tried many solutions such as array merge, array unique but it has not worked hundred percent.

So to get to the problem.

Query 1:

```
SELECT field_ipe_case_numbers_value
FROM meiscontent_type_inbound_parts_entry
RIGHT JOIN meiscontent_field_ipe_case_numbers 
    ON meiscontent_type_inbound_parts_entry.nid = meiscontent_field_ipe_case_numbers.nid
WHERE field_ipe_invoice_number_nid =661
AND field_ipe_quality_status_value = "Usable Stock"
ORDER BY field_ipe_case_numbers_value DESC
```

Resultset 1:

```
10695
10694
10693
10692
10691
10690
10689
10688
10687
10686
10685
10684
10683
10682
10681
10680
10679
10678
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT field_pnp_case_no_value
FROM meiscontent_type_packing_note_parts
RIGHT JOIN meiscontent_field_pnp_case_no 
    ON meiscontent_type_packing_note_parts.nid = meiscontent_field_pnp_case_no.nid
WHERE field_pnp_invoice_no_nid =661
ORDER BY field_pnp_case_no_value DESC
```

Resultset 2:

```
10695
10694
10693
10692
10691
10690
10689
10688
10687
10686
10685
10684
10682
10681
10680
10679
10678
```

**What is needed is the difference of these two resultsets.** which should be 10683 but I am getting 10686.

Thanks for looking and as I am trying various solutions, hope there is somebody out there who has a better understanding of this problem and proposes a workable solution. Cant I just work it out using a SQL statement rather than getting the results in the ARRAY and try to do the operations as I am trying to do now.

Comment: I am using Mysql as the database and php as the language to do these operations. Thank you for all the suggestions and I am going to try all of them and report accordingly. The results I have been getting so far is using array merge and array unique. Thanks again.

Comment: Guys this problem has now been solved using a solution suggested by @Mike_c and http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/619503-mysql-get-only-unique-values-from-2-tables/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution in php:

`array_diff ($array1 , $array2);` should be the right choice.

http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

HTH

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to just merge and de-duplicate the results of the two queries, then just do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `value` FROM (
    SELECT `field_ipe_case_numbers_value` AS `value`
    FROM ...
    UNION
    SELECT `field_...` AS `value`
    FROM ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what db you are using, but you could try:

(query1) EXCEPT (query2)

Edit: oops, I see it is mysql... you could try

query1 AND NOT EXISTS (query2)

although you will probably have to move the order by after the (query2)

Comment: wasn't this just tagged with 'mysql' ?

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0005 sec)

Comment: Removed the order by clause for the purpose of simplicity and there as an empty resultset.

Comment: Hmm... How about `query1 AND field_ipe_case_numbers_value NOT IN (query2)`

Comment: Thanks Mike Got it solved using the same thing you described here. Courtesy: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/619503-mysql-get-only-unique-values-from-2-tables/ . Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

On the SQL side, this should work:

```
SELECT field_ipe_case_numbers_value FROM <rest of first query>
EXCEPT
SELECT field_pnp_case_no_value FROM <rest of second query>
```

This should return everything in the first set that is not also found in the second set. (Reverse the order if necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

That should be solvable in pure SQL also. A naive approach would be to just do:

```
select column from table a where column not in (select column from table b)
union
select column from table b where column not in (select column from table a)
```